# Writing XML Snippets for XML in Visual Studio

Tags: xml, visual-studio, code-snippets

I've written a number of XML snippets (specifically snippets *for* XML files) in Visual Studio and I'm encountering an issue where I use the snippet and am done with the replacement parameters and I want to get out of the replacement part of it, I hit enter at the end of the first line and it takes my cursor back to the beginning of the line.

This is one example:

```
<Code Language="XML">
  <![CDATA[ <loop id="$Id$" repeat="$Repeat$" ordinal="$Ordinal$">
          //intentional empty line left here
  </loop>]]>
</Code>
```

I have left out the declarations for brevity.

This snippet generates (with params filled in):

```
<loop id="1" repeat="10" ordinal="1">
    | <-- would like cursor to end up here
</loop>
```

And I would like the cursor to end up inside the tag, but when I go to the end of the first line and hit enter, the cursor moves to the beginning of the first line and I have to go back to the end of the first line and hit enter again.

This doesn't seem to me like expected behavior, but maybe it is.

Comment: Which IDE?.....

Comment: @spender - VS - just added that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [end](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171418.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) variable to position the cursor:

```
<Code Language="XML">
  <![CDATA[ <loop id="$Id$" repeat="$Repeat$" ordinal="$Ordinal$">
          $end$
  </loop>]]>
</Code>
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171418.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

*$end$ marks the location to place the cursor after the code snippet is inserted.*

Comment: I _knew_ there was a tag that I was missing!